# How to store a list of values in Redis?

Tags: java, redis

I need to store a list of values using a key in Redis.

Until now we used `zadd()` with bulking of 1000 item per `add`, the problem is takes time and performance.

Is there any other option which can provide better performance ?

- The Redis is configured as Cluster

Comment: What are you doing/how are you reading these values? The data structure you use should fit the needs of the use case.

Comment: we are using `zrangebyscore` method in order to retrieve the data from Redis

Comment: @ItamarHaber The Redis is configured as Cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zadd](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) is used for sorted sets, and has O(log(N)) performance on insertion. What kind of data structure do you want to have? If a simple list is enough, you can just use [lpush](https://redis.io/commands/lpush), which has O(1) performance on insertion